# Connect to SQL Server 2012 with Windows Mobile 6

Tags: sql, vb.net, windows

I'm trying to set up a connection to our SQL Server 2012 in a Windows Mobile 6 application using Compact Framework 3.5, ADO .NET and VB .NET. For reference, I started with the code at http://vb.net-informations.com/ado.net-dataproviders/ado.net-sqlconnection.htm and adjusted it to our environment.

But when I use `cnn = New SqlConnection(connetionString)` I get an error message:

> Value of type 'System.Data.SqlClient.Sqlcommand' cannot be converted to 'System.Data.SqlClient.SqlConnection'.

I've looked for it on Google, but haven't found an answer that suited my situation. Could someone help me fix my code or provide me with more suitable code for connecting to SQL Server 2012 in Compact Framework 3.5?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well, your `cnn` variable is obviously of type `SqlCommand` and you're trying to assign `New SqlConnection(connectionString)` to it - which you can't.

Also, I'm pretty sure that you can not access an SQL Server 2012 from a Windows Mobile device.

Comment: He did declare cnn as SqlClient. But I do agree that you can't access SQL server from windows mobile. I had similar problem - ended up writing an ASP.NET application.

Comment: How would declaring as SqlClient help?!?  The `connectionString` (funnily enough) should be a string.

Comment: @ArtK How do you know how `cnn` is declared? I can't see it in his question.

Comment: @ Thorsten Dittmar - it's in the listing he provided a link to. I assumed that he can copy and paste or type the code as shown in the link.